# About an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

I recently learnt in yet another post of mine how to get the ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$ i.e. $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, specifically consisting of the group $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ of these two automorphisms:$$\alpha: x\mapsto x, \beta: x\mapsto3x$$

These two automorphism can ben gotten also considering the automorphism group of the general cyclic group of order $n$ in yet another post.

So far, so good.

Now, my brain usually starts running freely asking usually to myself: what about other automorphism? Can there be any?

So I started reasoning on this further automorphism: $$\gamma: x\mapsto5x$$

Let's check this is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} = \{0, \rho, 2\rho, 3\rho\}$

$$\gamma(e)=e$$$$\gamma(\rho)=5\rho=\rho$$$$\gamma(2\rho)=10\rho=2\rho$$$$\gamma(3\rho)=15\rho=3\rho$$

So, it's a legitimate automorphism sending $e\mapsto e$, since injective and also onto.

However, here this automorphism is manifestly behaving like the identity automorphism, i.e. $\alpha: x\mapsto x$.
This can be seen also directly like this:

$$\gamma(x)=5x = 4x + x = x$$
, considering $4x=0$ for any $x$, since cyclic $\pmod{4}$.

So, if all the above is correct: am I right to claim $\gamma$ is all in all yet another identity automorphism, already accounted in $\{\alpha, \beta\}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's only one identity automorphism.   Answer, yes, since $5x=x$ in $\Bbb Z_4$.

Comment: It is important to keep in mind that an automorphism (or any morphism of groups) is defined precisely by where it sends each element. If two automorphisms send each element to the same class, then the two automorphisms are the same by definition.

Comment: @Cpc, you are right, Sorry, I didn't meant there were two identity automorphisms. What's the right term to use: $\gamma$ Is "isomorphic" to $\alpha$?

Comment: They're the same one.  It's good you play around with this stuff.   You're going to find that,  whenever $t\equiv 1\pmod4$, then $1\to t$ is the identity.

Comment: In fact $\gamma$ is *equal* to $\alpha$.

Comment: If it helps, write out $\gamma$ and the identity function explicitly as sets (going back to intro proofs and thinking of a function as a subset of the Cartesian product). They should be literally the same set, hence they are equal, even though you've written the rule for how to calculate the image of an element under each one differently

Comment: Automorphisms are functions. Two functions are equal (identical, the same) if and only if they have the same domain, the same codomain, and they take the same value at each point in the domain. The function is not the set of i structions you follow to obtain the value. So the function mapping each element of $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ to itself and the one taking it to five times itself are the same function,  because they have the same domain, same codomain, and take the same values. Just like the value $5$ is the same as the value $2+3$, even though the "instructions" are different.

Comment: They are two different ways of writing the same function, kind of like $|x|$ and $\sqrt{x^2}$ on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two,  right?   $\rm{Aut}(\Bbb Z_4)\cong\Bbb Z_4^×\cong\Bbb Z_2$.

As I mentioned,  since the residue class of $1$ in $\Bbb Z_4$ consists in $$\{\dots-7,-3,1,5,9,13,\dots \}$$ there's sort of infinitely many ways to write the identity automorphism.

Ditto the other one, where $1\to3$.

Comment: And so the residue class of 3 in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ forms the other infinite ways $\beta$ can be written.

Comment: Yes indeed.   But typically we just work with the representatives $\{0,1,2,\dots,n-1\}$ for $\Bbb Z_n$.  It tends to simplify things.